# <option {% if 'condition.' == 'condition....'%}selected{%endif%}> </option> not working in Django custom select

Tags: python-3.x, django, jinja2, html-select

I am passing two objects **'editsub_obj'** and **'cat'** both key-value pairs to the template. 
The main aim is to **keep option tag selected** when name from both object list matches but the code is not working.

```
  <select class="form-control" id="" name="cat_name" required>
            {% if not editsub_obj %}

            {% for data in cat %}
                <option  value="{{data.id}}">{{data.category_name}}</option>
            {% endfor %}

            {% else %}

            {% for data in cat %}
                {% if editsub_obj.category_name == data.category_name %}
                <option   value="{{data.id}}" selected>{{data.category_name}}</option>
                {% else %}

                <option   value="{{data.id}}">{{data.category_name}}</option>

                {% endif %}

            {% endfor %}

            {% endif %}

   </select>
```

Expected :

selected should be selected with the category_name matches in both objects list.

Actual :

none of the options are showing as selected.

Comment: for debugging try display the values `{{editsub_obj.category_name}}` and `{{data.category_name}}` in template, to check they are equal

Comment: {{ editsub_obj.category_name}} will have one single value whomsoevers edit button was clicked, let's suppose 'Clothes'

Comment: {{ data.category_name}} it contains all the categories that exist in the category model. {'Electronics', 'Clothes', 'Accesories', etc}

Comment: then you have to use `in` ie `editsub_obj.category_name in data.category_name`. see my updated answer

Comment: still not working

Answer (score 1):

Your code can reduce to ::

```
    <select class="form-control" id="" name="cat_name" required>
        {% for data in cat %}
            <option value="{{data.id}}"
                {% if editsub_obj and editsub_obj.category_name in data.category_name %} 
                   selected
                {%endif%}>
                {{data.category_name}}
            </option>
        {% endfor %}
   </select>
```

Comment: Ya that's right but, selected is not appearing even when value matches.

Comment: check the rendered html source code and look whether `selected` is added in any option